IK LOCK doesn‘t work when I have a pole target？
I'm rigging an robot arm,when I didn't use a pole target,the IK lock stuff works smoothly,while I add a pole target it break my lock specifically the ik root,is that a bug?and I tried other constrain seems doesn't work either,how could I 


Yes, ik locks/limits on the first bone are ignored in the presence of the pole target; no, it's not a bug.  The pole target works by rotating the first bone in the chain.  The pole is not the direction the elbow points.  The pole is the direction the IK axis points (in a 2-bone chain, the direction that the first bone's +X points; modified for a longer chain but from the same base.) This bone's rotation can either be under the control of the pole, or under limited/locked IK control, not both.

I see，thx for reply！
